# How to mix pages and sub-categories in a url

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages

I have a series of products which are organized into categories like:

- Windows

  - Product Lines

    - Specific Window type post

Initially I created a page (/windows) which links to the individual product lines. Each Product Line (category) has the name and short description.

The problem I discovered is that the post category(also /windows) takes precedence over the page when you click on Windows in a menu. Taking you to the Windows category instead of the Windows page. Is it possible to create a url that consists of a mix of page, category and finally posts?

```
site.com/windows/serenity/casement
           ^       ^         ^
         Page   Category    Post
```

Is there a better method here? This is starting to seem sloppy to me. In the end, I'd like to keep the individual products as posts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Why not try something like this:

1. A permalink structure like this: `/%category%/%postname%/`
2. **Category:** Windows

   **Sub-Category:** Serenity

   Create a post and assign it to "Serenity" (sub-category), and publish it.

The post's URL would now look just the way you want it to: `http://site.com/windows/serenity/post-name/` and most importantly it should work the way you want it to as well.

Comment: I was still having the issue where the category is taking precedence over the page of the same name. In this case it was just simpler to switch to nested pages

Comment: @Fireflight _"...issue where the category is taking precedence over the page of the same"_ - it always will. While you can have same name, you can't have the same slug for both categories and pages.